# 503 error service unavailable php

Tags: php

I am reading xml file with the help of curl which has 20+MB and after that I am inserting data in database. But when I run then script (php script) then after some time browser show me service unavailable :( how can i over come

```
$curl = curl_init();




curl_setopt_array($curl, 
    Array(
        //CURLOPT_URL => 'http://blogs.guggenheim.org/map/feed/',
        CURLOPT_URL => $xmlurl,    
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'spider',
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 12000,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 3000,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'UTF-8'
    )
);
$data = curl_exec($curl);   
curl_close($curl);
```

Event I increase the execution time

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
php_value memory_limit 1024M
php_value max_execution_time 19000
php_value max_input_time 17200
```

Comment: You need to look in your PHP error log for the cause of the problem.

Comment: make sure php is reading your custom settings. Run php -i|grep php\.ini to see which php.ini is in use, or php --ini, or do echo phpinfo(). Can you ping that resource from your server?

Comment: is this your own server who's api your'e accessing?

Comment: in error log server run out of time but I have increase the time lime but it run out of it before reach time?

Comment: I had same issue. The problem disappears when i found that my antivirus blocked php-cgi. After i unblocked it, it works as expected